# JavaScript variable missing value

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm making a google sheet that writes to a SQL server periodically. This is my code so far, less the SQL stuff. It grabs the a variable from the last entry in the database ("User" in this test), and submits everything after it.

```
function connectToMySqlDB() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
  Logger.log('Starting query process... ');

//  Connect to DB and get last entry
  var lastline = "User"
  Logger.log('Found serial number of last enter in SQL Database: ' + lastline);

//  Find row of entry in goolge sheet
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = "";
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if (values[i][j] == lastline) {
        row = [i+1]
        Logger.log('Found serial number in row: ' + row);
      }
    }    
  }  

//  Get first unfilled row
  var crange = sheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues();
  var Clast = crange.filter(String).length;
  Logger.log('Found last row in C: ' + Clast);
  var cfin = [Clast - row]
  Logger.log('Slection will be: ' + row + ' rows.');

// select rows from entry to last filled row
  var selection = sheet.getRange(row,0,cfin,lastColumn)


//  Submit rows line by line to DB (from last entry to first unfilled)


//  Write one row of data to a table.


}
```

The error I get from the google error is:

```
The coordinates or dimensions of the range are invalid. (line 33, file "Code")
```

Using the debug tool, the variable "row" has no value. The log file however shows that it does work

```
[16-09-15 11:39:41:063 PDT] Starting query process... 
[16-09-15 11:39:41:064 PDT] Found serial number of last enter in SQL Database: User
[16-09-15 11:39:41:067 PDT] Found serial number in row: 26
[16-09-15 11:39:41:157 PDT] Found last row in C: 37
[16-09-15 11:39:41:158 PDT] Selection will be:  rows.
```

My guess is somehow "var cfin = [Clast - row]" is clearing the "row" variable. I can't figure out for the life of me how to get around this.

Comment: Why are you wrapping `row = [i+1]` and `var cfin = [Clast - row]` with square braces? You realise that will create you an array, right?

Comment: Looking at your double for loop it seems that the value of the row variable gets overwritten by the outer loop after you have found the target value. Add a flag and break out of the outer loop after you have found the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to want `row` to be a number, but you're wrapping its calculation in square braces, giving you an array of one element long. Remove the square braces.

```
row = i+1;
```

(As an aside, you're declaring it as a string, wont make a difference but its better to not do that!)

After that, you're making the same mistake with `cfin`. Dont wrap it in square braces if you simply want a number

```
var cfin = Clast - row;
```

---

You may also have a problem if `row` is set by being found, but then the outer loop will reset that variable. You can get round this by breaking out of both loops:

```
var row = -1;
for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < values[i].length; j++) {     
      if (values[i][j] == lastline) {
        row = i+1
        Logger.log('Found serial number in row: ' + row);
        break;
      }
    }    
    if(row > -1) break;
  }
```